# How to fetch data from, mongodb to html form fields?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb

```
database name is test1 and collection name is feedbacks 
this is app.js
```

I'm unable to get mongodb data in my html form field data is being inserted but i want to get intial values in my form help me out with this.since i am new to this i would like to have a simple explicit solution.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongodb = require('mongodb');

var dbConn = mongodb.MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test1');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/retrieve', function(req, res){
    post.find({}, function(err, feedbacks){
        if(err) res.json(err);
        else    res.render('retrieve', {posts: feedbacks});
    });
});
app.post('/post-feedback', function (req, res) {
    dbConn.then(function(db) {
        delete req.body._id; // for safety reasons
        var dd = db.db("test1");

        dd.collection('feedbacks').insertOne(req.body);
    });    
    res.send('Data received:\n' + JSON.stringify(req.body));
});


app.get('/view-feedbacks',  function(req, res) {
    dbConn.then(function(db) {
        var dd=db.db("test1");
        dd.collection('feedbacks').find({"Name":"shubham"}).toArray().then(function(feedbacks) {
            res.status(200).json(feedbacks);
        });
    });
});
app.get('/view-sahil',  function(req, res) {
    dbConn.then(function(db) {
        var dd=db.db("test1");
        dd.collection('feedbacks').insertOne({"name":"sahil","E-mail":"sahil@vibhuti.guru","comment":"jhdsfji"},function(feedbacks) {
            res.status(200).json("Data inserted");
            });
        });
    });
 app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, process.env.IP || '0.0.0.0' );
```

this is my `index.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="..app.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>mongodb</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Please fill data in the form below:</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="/">
        <label>Name:<input type="text" name="" value= feedbacks.name required></label>
        <br>
        <label>Email:<input type="text" name="Email" value="" required></label>
        <br>
        <label>Comment:<br><textarea name="comment"></textarea></label>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>


    <a href="/view-feedbacks">View Records</a>
    <a href="/view-sahil">insert dummy record </a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this is a wrong way `<a href="/view-feedbacks">View Records</a>` here `<a href="/view-feedbacks">View Records</a>`  is `REST` api so call this api with the help of `AJAX`

Comment: @ManjeetThakur Sir could you please elaborate this answer i am new to this i dont have much grasp over this .if possible write me full code i shall be thankful to you

Comment: which framework are you using?

Comment: @manjeet thakur nodejs  and angularjs

Answer (score 0):

You can call API from angularjs like this

```
var testApp = angular.module('testApp', []);

testApp.controller('testController' , function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.getRequest = function () {
        console.log("I've been pressed!");  
        $http.get("http://localhost/view-feedbacks")
            .then(function successCallback(response){
                $scope.response = response;
                // Print this value in html 
            }, function errorCallback(response){
                console.log("Unable to perform get request");
            });
    };

});
```

with jQuery, you can do like this

```
 $.ajax({  
       type: "GET",  
       url: "http://localhost/view-feedbacks",  
       dataType: "json",  
       success: function(resp){  

         console.log("resp", resp);  
       },  
       error: function(e){  
         alert('error', e);  
       }  
     });
```

Comment: sir i have to use nodejs file and html then how to use ajax

Comment: nothing happening sir .thank you i appreciate your effort

Comment: it was helpful sir